# ASP.Net printer friendly code

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, printing

I am new to ASP.Net using C#. I want to do a printer friendly page and my system should change the printer orientation to landscape automatically by default. The content includes images and text. I only want to show the content. How can I do this?

Comment: @Michael well, I'd say we've corrected every error that could possibly be in this question :)

Comment: Also, @jenny, do you use master pages then? I have a feeling you'd need to completely make a different page from your regular "web" page. This is a lot easier if you followed some separation between the view(markup) and the domain logic

Comment: @Earlz: there's always more... to haunt me in the middle of the night...

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at CSS for creating print-friendly pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

When you set the `media="print"` attribute, you're telling the browser to use that particular stylesheet instead of the regular one. There's a great article on CSS and print on [A List Apart, "CSS Design: Going to Print"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) by Eric Meyer.

<strike>And specifically for the landscape page orientation, try this in your CSS:</strike>

```
@page { size: landscape }
```

Update: [Daniel Ballinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54026/daniel-ballinger) was kind enough to point out the `size: landscape` attribute isn't supported in the majority of current browsers (if any).

Comment: I've had little luck in setting landscape printing through CSS. See also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249532/is-page-sizelandscape-obsolete

Answer (score 3):

You could try using CSS definitions that actively target printer output using [print media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). This will allow you to hide or show elements as required.

This can be done with either a reference to a separate style sheet or by using an @media rule within the existing style definitions.

> Specify the target medium within the
>   document language

```
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="print" HREF="print.css">
```

> Specify the target medium from a style
>   sheet with the @media or @import
>   at-rules.

```
@import url("print.css") print;
```

or

```
@media print {
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
}
```

I've looked at changing the print orientation in the past and the conclusion I came to was that was outside your ability to control in a website. I.e. there was no solution that worked well for the majority of browsers. See also [Is @Page { size:landscape} obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249532/is-page-sizelandscape-obsolete)