# Print in Landscape format

Tags: javascript, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)

I am using below code to show print window on button click:

```
function print_onclick() {
    window.print();
    return false;
}
```

I want the page to be printed in Landscape format. Is there any property I can add in above code to make it work ?

Additional Info:
Since my page width is 1280 px, when I print it on A4 paper with portrait orientation, the font becomes too small.
I want to print only 2 lines. If not landscape, is there a way I can fix the font size of those table cell/divs while printing ?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

you cannot set this in javascript, you have to do this with html/css:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  @page { size: landscape; }
</style>
```

EDIT: See this Question and the accepted answer for more information on browser support: [Is @Page { size:landscape} obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249532/is-page-sizelandscape-obsolete)

Comment: This doesnot seem to work for IE7.

Comment: do you really have to support ie7? if it is not a must, please do not do not care about ie7

Comment: It's a must for some people hereannow78. I'm on client site and that's their primary browser.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Firefox (version 24 at the moment), but it does work in Chrome (version 30). Generating a PDF is an alternative that would work in all browsers (although more work / more processing required on the server etc.)

Comment: Can second the fact that works for Chrome 36 but not Firefox 31.

Comment: not working in firefox

Comment: Does not work in Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m

Comment: Is this supposed to work in IE11?? it didn't work with me. The default print orientation is always portrait, I have to manually change it from settings

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size#browser_compatibility This still doesn't seem to be widely supported (No Firefox, No IE, No Safari) even in 2021.