# css select option page

Tags: html, css

I have some trouble with printing a div.
I'm generating different tables with a dropdown list, these tables are generated in the same `<div>`, that I then use to print.

```
<select id='lists'>
<option value='1'>table 1</option>
<option value='2'>table 2</option>
<option value='3'>table 3</option>
</select>
```

When I select option 1 I want the table to be printed `size: portrait;`, but when I select 2 or 3 I want it landscape `size: landscape;`.

Is there a way to do this with css?

Thanks

Comment: You could add a class to the div depending on your option and then use the css in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903427/different-page-orientation-for-printing-html

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use javascript?

```
$(function() {
    $('select[id="lists"] option').onChange(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 1){
          $('table').addClass('portrait');
                    .removeClass('landscape');
        } else {
          $('table').removeClass('portrait');
                    .addClass('landscape');
        }
    });
});
```

This is only an example. I'm no javascript/JQuery expert so you'll have to look into it. Don't think you can solve it using just CSS.