# print fpdf PDF in Landscape

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, printing, fpdf

Hi I created more tahn 20 templates in FPDF in lanscape oriantation fome a MYSQL DB to show it in an IFrame. But when I want to print it it will always use standart portait orientation and place the hole page on the top of the portait.

Ii there a way to change that? ( Yes i Know I can change the printer settings to landscape and than it will function but when i use it often i forget it often and I dont want to change the standart setting of the printer)

I would like a way to simply rotate the hole PDF or change the printersettings to landscape when i want to print it does anyone know a way to realise this?

P.S. i allready tried to the @page methode or to change the Orientation ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903427/different-page-orientation-for-printing-html?noredirect=1&lq=1))but it dosent work or destroy the rest of the Homepage.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: it's not about the fpdf...but your printer setting...if you using the plugin, then you should set via your pdf plugin or printer setting