# Programmatically set print page left, right, top, bottom margins

Tags: printing, set

How to programmatically set the printer (left, right, top, bottom) margins, paper size liek A4, A3 etc.. in asp.net web applications.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control a user's printer.
Printer settings are firmly in the domain of "user controlled".
If you want to decrease the margins you are out of luck. 
If you want to increase the margins you can just add margins, since the margins of your application will be applied to the 'printable area' of your paper, i.e. 5% default margin from printer + 5% margin in code will be 10% margin.

Answer (score 0):

This css rules are designed for that:

```
@page { 
    size: 210mm 297mm portrait;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;     
}
```

Maybe useful links:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size
- [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)