# get htmlpage in landscape mode

Tags: html, css

In the below code  a certificate is generated using the shown html code.i.e, this html is converted to pdf later and so on.My question is that when the html page is printed the following page the print always appears in a portrait mode .Can any one let me know how to convert this to landscape by making changes in the html,css code

```
     <body>
     <div style='text-align:center;background-image: url(merit);background-repeat:no-repeat;width:1650px;height:900px;padding-top:340px;font-family:\"Times New Roman\";'>
     <font style='font-size:90px;color:#122229;'>Certificate of merit</font><br/>
     <font style='font-size:35px;color:#212219;'>Awarded to </font><br><br>
     <font style='font-size:45px;color:#3f3c32;'><b>Tom</b></font><hr color='#666666' style='width:600px;'><br/><br/>
     <font style='font-size:60px;color:#993399;'>for the position</font><br/>
     <font style='font-size:60px;color:#3f3c32';>Mnnager </font><br/><br/>
              <font style='font-size:30px;color:#564782';>12-Feb-2010</font><hr color='#fffff' style='width:400px;'><br/>
     </div>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe different HTML->PDF converters could use different approaches. I.e. the answer will depend on what PDF converter you are using.
Maybe it will be enough to use standard HTML formating, pls see this link:
[Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)