# How to print an image completely filling an A4 or other format?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a little issue if I print images with Chrome or Firefox. I haven't found how to get rid of white borders in portrait or landscape.
This [stackoverflow-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371822/how-can-i-print-an-image-in-a-web-page-fitting-the-paper-size-a3-a4-a5-etc) seems to not works for me sadly.

Currently I use this code:

```
    echo "<body onload=\"window.print()\" onfocus=\"window.close()\">";

    echo "<style type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\">";
    echo "@page { size: auto; }";
    echo "</style>";

    echo "<img src=\"". $dirname . '/' . $photo ."\">";
```

I get the same result as drag and drop it from windows folder to internet navigator like this exemple:

Chrome is set as: 
- Landscape
- Colors
- A4
- Marges none

[image: bug]

Comment: *This stackoverflow-solution seems to not works for me sadly.* - The SO question you linked to says that this isn't possible.

Comment: @BSMP I understood it was only not possible with IE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to apply  the  container css :

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
}
```

then instead of using **img** tag use background image + size **cover**

```
body {
    background-image:  url(images/background.svg);
    background-size:   cover;                      /* <------ */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;            /* optionally, center the image */
}
```

source:

- [page size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16650459/1427338)
- [background image size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265035/1427338)

Comment: Great great answer this is working very good ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Your image file probably has different dimensions than the paper size, so unless you want to stretch the image to fill the page, or use something like `background-size: cover;` there will always be a margin

Comment: Image size was bigger than A4. Bleuscyther found the solution thanks anyway for help !