# how can I print page horizontal in CSS

Tags: css, printing, landscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)

How can I print page horizontal in CSS.

```
size : landscape
```

or

```
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(Rotation=1);
```

code blocks are not working. I try to write these block into body tag class. So, who can help me ?

**--------- Edit ---------**

Here is the code I use this now :

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    .land {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    }
</style>
<body class="land">
```

Comment: Answered pretty extensively here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html

Comment: You can't change a users print settings within a web page

Comment: I stand corrected, though it seems to have significant issues! :)

Comment: @TomGerken Yes I founded that page and try all these code blocks. But result is same.Every time give me vertical.

Comment: if you are talking about the Orientation of the paper (portrait or landscape), then this is a setting of the print option of the app (in your case the browser) and can't be influenced by css

Comment: Indeed, Liam, but you can manipulate the css whenever the person wants to print it to make it ink friendly, such as leaing pictures out of it. Its done by the propperty `@media print` in this case, he can put `@media print{@page {size: landscape}}` .. more info here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html

Comment: I dont know how it is but I tried this today and it works now. But I didnt change anything. Thanks anyway.