# Report Viewer always print portrait

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, orientation

Currently, I am using Crystal Report and C#. My report type is landscape and its show correctly in report viewer but when I print, That report print as the portrait.

I also try by adding like this =>

```
 report.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape;
```

But it's not working. I already change the report orientation in crystal report as Landscape. But it's still not working.

All of the printer settings is landscape. (Currently, I am testing with Microsoft OneNote).

Previously, These reports are working properly. But I have no idea why it's not working now.

Could u please provide me a possible solution?

Comment: You might wanna check the generated file using some other software as well..Also I would recommend checking your print settings as well..One more possibility is addition/removal of any new columns in your report..that may also be affecting the the printing of document.

Comment: @BhawnaJain I was a bit change in the current report file, But I redownloaded the old (working report file) from server and test and now it's not working. I create new landscape report and test and its also not printing landscape.

Comment: Hey Loran, so the change you mention, was it related to addition of more content, if yes, then you have to check the settings at the time of giving print command. Also see this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037737/print-html-table-in-landscape

Comment: @BhawnaJain This one is not the web app.

Comment: could you update this in your question

Comment: Try with another printer. Maybe Microsoft Print for PDF or Microsoft XPS Document Writer. I believe it is a printer setting issue, like @BhawnaJain pointed out. See what happens to eliminate or confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

That one is because of Crystal Report Run-time version. At the beginning, I just installed the version `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_23` And then I just down grade to `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12`(but i forgot this part and i don't think it won't effect).

That's why that error is occur.Because i tested on another computer that install `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_23` and It is working.That answer is may be or may be not the answer for u but that one solved my problem.