# Print html table in ladscape mode

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table, landscape

Given the following html code:

```
<html>
<style>
    div.container > table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    div.container > table > tbody > tr > td {
        border: 1pt solid;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to print to A4 portrait orientation in the following way:

1. First page contains "Hi" in portrait orientation
2. Second page contains the table, but rotated 90 degrees. Said otherwise, second page must be printed in landscape orientation
3. Third page contains "Hello" in portrait orientation

I tried adding the following style:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: a4 portrait;
    }
    div.container > table {
        break-before: page;
        break-after: page;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
}
```

The problem are that:

1. The table is not aligned to the upper left corner of the page
2. **The table is sized in portrait mode before being rotated**. This means the width of the table is still the one in the portrait mode

How can I achieve my objective?

Requirements:

1. The HTML code must stay exactly as it is. You cannot put the table in another div or modify it in any way
2. Only CSS, and, if that is not possible pure Javascript

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037737/print-html-table-in-landscape) is no good because (1) the first solution prints everything in landscape mode, not just the table (2) the second solution has the same problems of the solution I propose.

EDIT:

Tried this but didn't work:

```
@media print {
    @page general{
        size: a4 portrait;
    }

    @page rotated {
        size: a4 landscape;
    }

    div.container {
        page: general;
    }

    div.container > table {
        break-before: page;
        break-after: page;
        page: rotated;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can't choose what to print on which page in HTML. Every printer has some settings like margin and offset. What you can do is to draw it in different canvas, or even better, create a pdf (possible also with javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Click on the page (on the text "hello" for example) to open the print preview.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
window.print()
});
```

```css
table
{
transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0%, -100vw);
transform-origin: left top;
display: block;
position: relative;
break-before: page;
break-after: page;
margin: 0px -20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<style>
    div.container > table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    div.container > table > tbody > tr > td {
        border: 1pt solid;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: here my print preview:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But the second text ("Hi") is in the same page of the left over of the table. I would need that text in a new page, or the table contained in a single page

Comment: I added the print preview I see on my browser. I have the table on a single page. This is the problem of the HTML print: you can't be sure it is the same on every printer. You can try to add `display:block;width:100vw;break-before: page;` to p, maybe will set it to a new page. Or set it on `p:last-child`