# Landscape Printing in IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, css

Why `@page {size: landscape}` doesnt't work with IE8 and IE9 but works fine with Chrome. How can I fix this in IE8 and IE9?  any idea/suggestions

Reason I am using landscape is because my table has 7 columns and while printing, it clips the right side of the table

Below is the css style which I am using

```
<style> 
@media print
{
    @page {size: landscape}

     #tableContainer {height:100% !important; }
     #tableContainer {overflow:hidden !important;}
     #table{height:100% !important;}
     #tabletr{display:table-row !important ;}
     }  
</style>
```

`#table` is a `<table>` and `#tableContainer` is the `<div>` that holds the `<table>`

Comment: This asked before than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807044/printing-landscape-or-portrait-in-firefox-and-ie-8.

Comment: Also see the article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16733/using-css-to-force-Landscape-Print-in-IE