# Has anyone been able to successfully print in landscape mode in Chrome using CSS3?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, printing

I've been following this question - [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html/1392794#1392794)

I include - @media print{@page {size: landscape}}
in my CSS file.

I'm aware that not all browsers support this, but there's conflicting information online where some people say this works and some say it doesn't.

I've been trying to do this in Chrome and it won't work. I wanted to know if anyone has been able to successfully do this on Chrome? Or does this not work on Chrome(and I should stop wasting time on it)?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Comment: Does it give you proper pages if you explicitly select landscape printing from the print dialog?

Comment: @Pointy Yes, explicitly selecting landscape works as expected

Comment: Well, that may be the best you can expect - that it pays attention and consumes the page width.  Printing support across all major (and minor I guess) browsers is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63

```
<head>
  <style>
    @media print {
      @page {
        size: letter landscape;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
```