# Page-Spanning Printing HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

SO is probably not the right place for this, but I may have missed a trick with my HTML/CSS.

I have written an application that outputs to HTML, for convenience. The page it produces is big, insofar as it *should* span multiple pages, both horizontally and vertically. However, unlike spreadsheets, browsers don't seem to do the "across then down" or "down then across" style printing and, if the page isn't shrunk-to-fit, it's just clipped at one page's width.

Short of printing to a custom page size that accommodates the full width and height, is there anything I can do to get the page-spanning printing I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a programmatic solution, so did this:

- Print oversized HTML on to paper big enough to accommodate everything (e.g., A0) to PDF.
- Adobe Reader (and probably other viewers) have a "Poster Print" option, that does the tiling automatically with an optional scaling factor: Do this, either to PDF if you need to do any further layout processing, or to your printer directly.
- ???
- Profit

A bit of a weak link in my pipeline -- until I can generate tiled PDFs directly -- but c'est la vie!

Answer (score 1):

For the problem `Landscaping` is one method you can try out.

Refer here:- [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html?rq=1)

But I would recommend to convert it to a PDF before printing which will be more comfortable.

Comment: +1 for the info: I read the W3C spec and while it implies that the NxM tiled printing is possible using this, it's up to browsers to implement it, which they don't seem to... I ultimately went with printing on really large paper :P