# how to show land scape in css3

Tags: html, css, print-preview

I am making a report using html css3.In which have many columns,I want to print a landscape using html css3.Is there any option in css3.Actually i  rotated the body and table also but half part of table is showing and half part of table is cutting/hiding because my table one side is showing inside the top side of the page.When I checked in print preview.

```
  Using following code is css for rotating the body or table but table is cutting
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

Guide me for land scape

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@page` rule in CSS

```
@page {
  size: A4 landscape;
  margin: 24pt 10pt;
}
```

For more information see the article here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm

Comment: that is css2 feature.I am using css3.Is there any option in css3

Comment: You can use both CSS2 and CSS3 together. If your browser supports 3 it will support 2 as well; you can use them interchangeably.