# php html create email and print in landscape

Tags: php, html, email, landscape

In PHP I have the following code that sends an email.  Is there someway to encode it so that the email, when printed by the recipient, automatically prints in landscape?

```
          $email_subject = 'Crew List';

          // instantiate mailer
          $mail = new PHPMailer();        
          $mail->IsSMTP();
          $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // enable SMTP authentication
          $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";      // sets the prefix to the server
          $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server 
          $mail->Port = 587;              // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
          $mail->Username = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
          $mail->Password   = "xxxxxx"; 
          $mail->SetFrom("yyyyyy@gmail.com");         // set From:
          $mail->AddAddress("zzzzzz@gmail.com");      // set To:
          $mail->Subject = $email_subject;            // set Subject:

          $body =  $msg;

 *        $mail->MsgHTML($body);             

          if ($mail->Send() === false)// send mail
           {
             apologize_index("Google was not able to connect, try again later");      
           }   



          $mail->ClearAddresses();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "prints in landscape"

Comment: most emails are printed in portrait when printed by the recipient.  I want to override the default parameters that they have set up so when they print this email it automatically prints in landscape without them having to change their default options

Comment: No, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution you may have a try:

Most of the email clients in this world supports HTML format. so you may use CSS to have a try.

Please have a look:

[Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)

So, generate your email as HTML format, and combine those CSS.
The support for email clients is very mixed.

OR, why not just generate a landscape PDF as an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's good option to make your email in the pdf format which should be in the landscape orientation.