# page size:landscape; firefox does not work

Tags: css, printing

I want to use landscape printing. In firefox it does always print in potrait? Other browsers use landscape.@media print
{
    @page {
        size:landscape;
        margin:0; 
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some fixes floating about the web for this, such as:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    .page
    {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
     -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    }
</style>
```

but there are some other great examples and a lot of information in this SO question here: [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)