# Force landscape orientation in CSS

Tags: css, printing

I do set to landscape the size property of a CSS file to print pages in landscape

```
@page {
          margin: 0.1cm;
          size: landscape;
          orientation: landscape;
          size: A4;
```

Some pages are printed into portrait orientation, some in landscape orientation.

How can i detect and force the pages to be printed in landscape using CSS ?

Comment: Did you try this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html

Comment: i try : @page {  size: landscape; as the solution says the final try is to use pdf as not all browsers accept this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is first you write `size: landscape;` but then you write `size: A4;`
If not provided, **domPDF** is rendering like default portrait, and it overwrites the landscape.
Set the second parameter landscape and it will work out.

```
size: A4 landscape;
```

Answer (score 17):

The CSS you provided has problems:

1. The bracket does not close (missing `}`),
2. You overwrite `size` with `A4`
3. `orientation` seems to exist for media queries, but not as an attribute ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation)). Hence you can check the orientation, but not set it.

I tried

```
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
}
```

in Chrome 60 on Linux and it worked. Seems not to work in Firefox, though.

You could set the `width` and `height` of the `<body>` to whatever you need (only for printing by using the media query) just like [paper.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper-css/0.2.3/paper.css) does.

### Alternative

You could add

```
body {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Seems to be [safe to use](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it works with:

```
@page {
   size: landscape letter;
}
```