# How to print landscape PDF in portrait

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I want to print my PDF file which is in landscape but when I print it in Firefox using iframe it will print the landscape file in portrait.

I know I can change it on the printer config. But I dont want to do it every time or change my printer settings.

To make it more complicated, I can´t install plugins on the server.

So is it possible to tell the printer to print it in portrait?

Comment: This question is not clear. It sounds like you're asking if there's a way to "hint" at the browser that the print mode should be landscape (the user would still be able to change it) but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: I can print the pdf file but it just cast the landscape file on the top potion of the portrait when i change the printer settings to landscape its ok but i have to change it manually everytime i print it and this I dont want that

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html would be of help

Comment: this i tried allready didn`t work -.-