# set page orientation using header

Tags: php, layout, header, openoffice-writer

Given a php file, I export its output to an .odt file (OpenOffice Writer) by means of the following lines:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.odt"');
```

I can't figure out how to set the page orientation to **landscape**. By default, it is set to portrait.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using CSS:

```
@page {
  size: landscape;
}
```

It seems to be working, at least on Firefox.
The answer was here:
[Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)