# How to print Web page in landscape (firefox IE11)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, landscape

```
  @page {
    size: 11in 8.5in;
  }
```

Did not work in IE/FF;
`transform: rotate(270deg);` work only for first page;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html

Comment: can i do this without convert to pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved my problem:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(x, 0) scale(x)
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(x, 0) scale(x)
transform-origin: 0 0
```