# CSS - Print html document

Tags: css, css-print

I have a report in html format that needs to be printed both in landscape and in portrait
Can I use "@page {size: landscape / portrain}" property for individual blocks?

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html

Comment: It does not describe the work of different blocks, personally I could only apply to the entire page

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to hide the elements that you wouldn't want to appear in the print.

```
<div class="hide">
    <p> Anything in here will not print</p>
</div>
```

And you'd add the following to your CSS:

```
@media print
.hide{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: I don't need to hide anything, I need to assign size: portrain for a separate container

Comment: Oh gotcha, so you want to print the page, and have the container change it's orientation just for the print?

Comment: Yes, I can provide a screenshot so that you understand how I need to do

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add the CSS code that represents the report?