# CSS to force HTML page to print in A4 Landscape

Tags: html, css, pdf

I want to print a single HTML page forced to A4 size in landscape orientation.

I tried many things but failed.

my current code is

```
 @media print {
    body{
        width: 29.7cm;
        height: 21cm;
        margin: 20mm 20mm 0mm 10mm; 
     } 
}
```

but i am unable to force the page to landscape orientation.

Please help

Comment: I want to make pdf in a4. i succeeded with forcing it to a4 put not to landscape

Comment: This one? [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)

Comment: Don't tell me about it. Flag it. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)