# I have HTML report which need to be viewed in portrait mode but need to be printed, rotated, in landscape mode, how to do this?

Tags: html, css, printing

this is code that i tried, modified from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069821/2752387

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: #CCCCCC;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .output {
      width: 8.5in;
      height: 11in;      
      border: 1px solid black;            
      background: white;
    }
    @media print {
      @page {size: landscape}
      .output {        
        transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-8.5in, 0);
        transform-origin: 0 0;             
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        background: white; 
      }    
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="output">
    my text
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is when it print, somehow the bottom part of the content split
to second page

[image: printpreview]

how do i fix this ?

i expect it to print in 1 page

Comment: What size paper is in the printer?

Comment: letter page size

Comment: Is the printer set up for borderless printing?

Comment: When i said print, I'm trying to save as pdf, as per screen shot. I expect to show 1 page in the chrome print preview.